# Symfony: How to load workflows configuration from a third-party bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-workflows

I'm creating a bundle that uses `Workflow` component.

I've created a Workflow in the file `Resources/config/workflows.yml`.

Then I've tried to load this file automatically from the `AcmeAwesomeBundleExtension` class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $loader        = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));

    // This loads the Workflows
    $loader->load('workflows.yml');

    $loader->load('services.yml');

    ...
    }
}
```

This is the content of the `workflows.yml` file:

```
framework:
    workflows:
        the_name:
            type: workflow
            supports:
                - My\Bundle\Namespace\Entity\MyEntity
            places:
                - wait_config
                - configured
            transitions:
                give_config:
                    from: wait_config
                    to: configured
```

Nothing so complex for the moment.

But this returns me this error:

> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:
>
> ```
> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "framework" (in /U    
> sers/Aerendir/Documents/JooServer/_Projects/Coommercio/Apps/app-coommercio-
>
> www/vendor/myvendor/myawesomebundle/src/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/workflows.yml). Looked for namespace "framework", found none
> ```

Obviously all is loaded well if I manually import the file directly in my `config.yml` file, the one of my app:

```
imports:
    - { resource: '@MyAwesomeBundle/Resources/config/workflows.yml' }
```

**So, how can I load automatically the workflows from my third-party bundle?**

Answer (score 4):

The solution is really simple.

Instead of loading the configuration in the `MyAwesomeExtension::load()` method, the `workflow` has to be loaded in the method `MyAwesomeExtension::prepend()`:

```
class MyAwesomExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $loader        = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        ...
    }

    /**
     * ! ! ! LOAD THE WORKFLOW HERE ! ! !
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('workflows.yml');
    }
```

This way my third-party bundle can load the configuration required to create the `workflow`.

More information can be found on the Symfony's documentation about the `ConfigComponent`: [How to simplify configuration of multiple bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html).